# Do my non-normal data (per S-W test) require the use of nonparametric alternative to linear regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, residuals

First time posting here so please be kind. My sample size is 64 (31, and 33 in each group, betw subj design) and when testing for normality found significant Shapiro-Wilk statistic for each subset of data (p<.02 and p< .001). I'm not expert enough yet to judge how problematic the data are for linear regression modeling by visually inspecting the residual plots. My main analysis is a simple linear regression but I also wanted to run a multiple regression w/ two predictors.

Is it okay to use linear regression on these data? If not, what are my best options given the two analyses I'm trying to do?

Below is the qqplot (edit: now the scatterplot) for the simple regression. The residuals for the multiple reg look a little better but couldn't post them because I don't have enough reputation points :/

[image]

[image]

Comment: The residuals are almost never normally distributed when we fit linear regression models.  It's a nice property to have but not really essential in my opinion.  Since your model is so simple I think you could make do with a visual inspection of whether or not the model provides a good fit, regardless of what family of distributions the residuals might belong to.

Comment: Regression models don't entail assumptions about marginal distributions. Are these the residuals? Quite possibly a bigger deal here is that your data seem to fall into several discrete clumps. So, the idea of a normal distribution is moot in any case, regardless of Shapiro-Wilk. More crucially, does linear regression make sense if your data are effectively discrete? It might/might not. We don't have enough information to advise well.

Comment: @NickCox this is likely a function of the fact that the dv is percent accuracy out of 9 trials. I didn't think this sort of dv was problematic for linear regression though?

Comment: @dsaxton, that works for me but I'm not an expert at visually inspecting plots, and texts I've consulted haven't helped me here. Do the plots look reasonable to you?

Comment: You don't need to be an expert to see if a straight line fits the data.  It's not clear from the Q-Q plot but would be clear from a scatter plot.

Comment: By percent you appear to mean proportion. Either way, a bounded response **could be** highly problematic as nothing in $Y = Xb$ guarantees compatibility with the built-in limits of the response, nor is linearity usually a natural shape for the dependency of response on predictors. You are fitting the so-called linear probability model by the sound of it, which has some defenders. But very many statistical people would lean towards something like a logit model.

Comment: Your residuals aren't symmetric about zero. Not seriously so, but itself worth taking further.

Comment: @NickCox, I'll look into using a logit model, although presumably the same issue applies re: non-normal residuals? I now show the scatterplot (w/ jitter so that you can see the number of points at magnitudes of the dv -- the model predicts the group means, coded w/ contrast codes, -.5 and +.5). It's not obvious to me whether the slope is a good fit to the data. The question really is whether the means are a good representation of the groups, which is why it is informative to look at the distribution of the data by group. What kind of further investigation would you recommend?

Comment: Logit models aren't expected to have normal residuals; indeed that's not really possible.

Comment: Linear regression would likely be robust. The SW test should be used in the whole sample. In any case a scatterplot of the data would help us help you.

Comment: The Shapiro-Wilk test is a red herring here. Neither data nor residuals can be normal, exactly, if the response is a proportion; if they are normal approximately, that's not directly relevant to any sensible analysis. From a plot of the data, which I understand to have been given already, a linear probability model is not too bad a fit and may be acceptable in practice, but its residuals are necessarily bounded, as an observed proportion $p$ can only give rise to residuals in the interval $[-p, 1 - p]$. (I set aside the pathology that a linear probability model can predict outside $[0,1]$.)

Comment: Thanks @NickCox! So just to make sure I understand, the SW test is not really valid in this case because of the nature of the  response variable? I'm not sure I follow why approximately normal residuals is not relevant to any sensible analysis (do you mean not relevant to a logit model?) I will use a logit model if it's more appropriate. Another alternative is a nonparametric test (e.g., Wilcoxon rank-sum test). Any thoughts on that? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd say the Shapiro-Wilk test was irrelevant rather than invalid. You need, in my view, software supporting generalised linear models and logit link, binomial family and "robust" standard errors. If the data are similar to what has been plotted, it should be straightforward to show a implementation if you posted the raw data. Your scatter plot with straight line suggests that a linear probability model may be an adequate model,  but better model should be possible. However, why your predictor is bimodal and whether that influences an appropriate model need to be clarified.

Comment: I can't see how a Wilcoxon test is any sense an alternative; what here two distinct groups? If it's whatever produces two modes, it wouldn't use all the data.

Comment: @NickCox my predictor is categorical -- in my experiment I randomly  assigned participants to one of two groups/conditions and tested the effect on a cognitive test (response variable: proportion of trials on which the participant responded correctly). Does this change your recommendation? Thanks! Edit: I use Andy Field's stats text as guidance and he recommends Wilcoxon rank sum when the data don't meet the assumptions of linear regression. The test is pretty straightforward/easy to understand and seems to make sense, but I'd rather use a parametric test if there is one that is appropriate.

Comment: No. You could use logit with a binary predictor.